# What is the regular c++ equivalent of the Arduino "delay" function?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a countdown timer in Visual Studio.

I've tried using the "delay" function as if I'm coding an Arduino program, but the error list said it was an unidentified function.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: What does the "Delay" function *do* in the Arduino code? Does it just suspend the thread, or does it involve some kind of callback?

Comment: Is this an event driven program with a GUI? If so what API / framework are you using? Normally you don't want to sleep in a GUI application. Instead you want to use a timer of some sort provided by the API / framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)  is the standard equivalent.  It suspends the current thread for the duration specified.

For example, this would print "Before", wait one second, and then print "After":

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Before" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "After" << std::endl;
}
```

Be careful using this in event-driven contexts such as GUI threads, since it could prevent events from being handled in a timely manner and cause your application to hang or be killed by the OS.  GUI toolkits usually provide their own safe alternatives that let them continue to process events and avoid that problem.

---

There are also similar functions supplied by various platform APIs.  Most commonly you'll come across the Windows [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) or the POSIX [`sleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html), [`usleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html), and [`nanosleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html).  For portability it's a good idea to use the standard `std::this_thread::sleep_for`, but the platform functions can be used if it's not available for whatever reason (using C++03 or earlier, no standard library, etc).

Comment: It did not work for me unfortunately, the visual studio error list said most of  the stuff after "::" does not exist in std, is unidentified, or not a type

Comment: @NigelA. You need to include `<thread>`, `<chrono>`, and `<iostream>`.

Comment: And compile with `-std=c++11` (or higher).

Comment: No syntax errors, but the program still does not work. Here is the code for reference:                                                                    
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void MinuteCountdown()
{
 int second;
 for (second = 60;second > 0; --second)
 {
  cout << second << endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
 }
}

int main()
{
 return 0;
}

Comment: @NigelA. Code does not format well in comments. I suspect this is by design to keep comments short. The code you gave does not call the countdown function. Try `int main()
{
    MinuteCountdown();
    return 0;
}`

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your C++ standard.

If your code targets C++11 or above (which by now you really should) you can use `std::this_thread::sleep_for` from `<thread>`.

If not, then there is not portable way and you should use platform dependent functions.